# In some applications share menu my application name is not displaying

Tags: android

In Some applications share menu My app Name is not comming with app logo and logo is coming to the center of the screen horizontally.

and this is my Manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity
            android:name=".LandingPageActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Please see this image for detailed description.[image]

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I posted my AndroidManifest.xml. Can you please look into that.

Comment: Hmm, thats not the whole manifest ...

Comment: I posted the whole manifest. Can you please look into that.

Comment: Add `android:name="@string/app_name"` to `<application....` in your manifest

Comment: Thank for your answer. But actually in place of android:name in application tag I specified my application class which extends Application class.

Comment: No. My problem was not fixed now. Because I cant give @string/app_name in place of android:name in application tag because of declaring Application class.